# How to determine Solr data change for a query from a particular time

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am indexing documents in Solr on the basis of multiple fields. My documents in Solr are getting updated (new documents being added, existing documents updated and deleted) constantly for which Solr will do the re-indexing.
If I do a complex query on the basis of multiple fields and some sorting criterion, I get some result set. Now I am interested in knowing if the result set returned from Solr has changed since the last time I fetched my result set. In case, the result set has changed, I want to fetch the data again and refresh view on the client application with the new result set.
Is there a way in Solr to know if the result for a Solr query has changed since a particular time?

Comment: No. You have to do it on your own.